# Division operation in HQL select

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

Here is my HQL query

```
    select 'Async Event Processing/' + coalesce(sje.outcome,'SUCCESS'), sje.duration
from ScheduleJobExecution sje left outer join sje.scheduledJob as sj where sj.id = 1 group by sje.outcome, sje.duration
```

The HQL query returns records in the following format where sje.duration is in milli seconds

```
[Async Event Processing/SUCCESS, 51225]
```

I want the `sje.duration` in seconds so i tried `sje.duration/1000` in select but it didnt work

NOTE: I input HQL query in a UI which accepets only  HQL not any other libraries like Math and objects like session

Comment: What is the unit of duration? Also, are you getting any error?

Comment: So, is it minute? or microseconds?

Comment: duration is in milli seconds(actual duration 51225), I want it in seconds(51225/1000 = 51.225)

Comment: even then, the select statement looks awkward, what is your actual HQL?